# Выравнивание по вертикали

Tags: css, вёрстка

Как с помощью CSS выравнять элемент по вертикали?

Answer (score 2):

Использую `line-height`
[line-height](http://htmlbook.ru/css/line-height)

Пример

```
<div class="test">test</div>
```

css

```
.test {
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6ko6f5a/)

Comment: можете показать пример?

Comment: @ikerya вот пример [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6ko6f5a/)

Comment: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1248 - полный список

Answer (score 2):

## 6 способов центрирования элемента неизвестного размера по вертикали и горизонтали

**Вариант №1: Flexbox**

Один из современных и самых простых способов центрирования – использование `display: flex`.

```css
body {
    margin: 0; /* for Demo only */
    height: 100vh; /* for Demo only */
    background: black; /* for Demo only */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img width="100px" src="https://www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png">
</div>
```

**Вариант №2: CSS Grid**

Grid – наше ближайшее и светлое будущее! Никогда прежде выравнивание блоков не была такой простой и вряд ли в скором времени что-то превзойдет CSS Grid. Хотя этот пример и похож очень на предыдущий, возможности Grid гораздо шире. В общем, если не научились работать с flexbox – можете смело его пропускать и разбираться с CSS Grid.

```css
body {
    margin: 0; /* for Demo only */
    height: 100vh; /* for Demo only */
    background: black; /* for Demo only */
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img width="100px" src="https://www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png">
</div>
```

**Вариант №3: центрирование через псевдоэлемент**

Мой самый любимый способ. Несмотря на то, что в последнее время стал использовать flexbox – выравнивание через псевдоэлемент навсегда останется в моём сердце.

```css
body {
    margin: 0; /* for Demo only */
    height: 100vh; /* for Demo only */
    background: black; /* for Demo only */
    text-align: center;
}

body:before {
   content: '';
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.block {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img width="100px" src="https://www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png">
</div>
```

**Вариант №4: line-height**

Один из самых глупых вариантов, который хоть и подходит для выравнивание блока неизвестной высоты, но требует фиксированную высоту родителя (в других способах высота родителя указана лишь для примера). Кстати, этот способ также не подойдет для многострочного текста.

```css
body {
    margin: 0; /* for Demo only */
    height: 100vh; /* for Demo only */
    background: black; /* for Demo only */
}

.block {
    line-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.block img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img width="100px" src="https://www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png">
</div>
```

**Вариант №5: position absolute**

Один из моих любимых вариантов. Идеально подходит для позиционирования попапов – они должны быть поверх остального контента, а их высота никогда неизвестна, как и высота экрана пользователя.

```css
body {
    margin: 0; /* for Demo only */
    height: 100vh; /* for Demo only */
    background: black; /* for Demo only */
    position: relative;
}

.block {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <img width="100px" src="https://www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png">
</div>
```

**Вариант №6: table-cell**

Самый древний вариант, которым пользовались на заре Интернета и во времена рассвета табличной вёрстки. Таблицами уже давно никто не верстает, но имитировать их поведение через CSS ради достижения результата – почему бы и нет?

```css
body {
    margin: 0; /* for Demo only */
    height: 100vh; /* for Demo only */
    background: black; /* for Demo only */
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.block {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <img width="100px" src="https://www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Можно ответить в комментариях, за что минусы?